# Watcher not firing on initialize, but works in mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When watching a property/prop the initial value does not trigger a change.
The watcher doesn't work until it is set a second time after initialization.

```js
export default {
    props: ['value', 'min', 'max'],
    watch:{
        value(){
            console.log("FIRED!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the `immediate` option on the watcher makes it fire on mount.

```js
export default {
    props: ['value', 'min', 'max'],
    watch:{
        value: {
            immediate: true,
            handler(){
                console.log("FIRED ON MOUNT!");
            }
        },
    }
}
```

As is documented here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch